# Can I access a Scala object's val without parentheses from Java?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

Given the following Scala object:

```
object ScalaObject {
    val NAME = "Name"
}
```

It appears that the Scala compiler generates a parameterless method to access the `NAME` field.  However, when I try to access this field from Java, it looks like the only way to access this field is as a parameterless method like:

```
System.out.println(ScalaObject$.MODULE$.NAME());
```

Is there a way to coax the Scala compiler to allow Java to access the `val` per the expected Java idiom as:

```
System.out.println(ScalaObject$.MODULE$.NAME);
```

Comment: Does the same happen with lower-case vals?

Comment: It's not the expected *Java* idiom by the way, it's the expected *Scala* idiom.  In terms of bytecode, Scala (almost?) always exposes fields as getter methods with the same name.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle, I'm not sure what you're saying.  In Java, it's expected to access static final fields without parentheses because its the only way to do so.  What you seem to be suggesting is that in Scala, the expected technique is to use getter methods.  Regardless, whatever is Scala's preferred technique, doesn't seem relevant to a Java client of an API that happens to be implemented in Scala.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly, the answer is no, because scala isn't generating just a field, but a pair of methods for accessing it.  However, annotating the scala `val` with `@scala.reflect.BeanProperty` will produce Java-style getter and setter methods.

so while you wouldn't be able to say (in your case)

```
ScalaObject$.MODULE$.NAME
```

You *would* be able to say

```
ScalaObject$.MODULE$.getNAME()
```

Which would be a more Java-like idiom, just not the one you were hoping for.

N.B.  I haven't tried `@BeanProperty` with an all-uppercase name like that, so I'm not sure what it would actually produce.

Answer (score 1):

No, because in bytecode there are different instruction to access field and invoke method. You must patch Javac then (and your IDE syntax highlighter).

Comment: I think the OP expects some annotation to get scalac to produce Java fields, not a way to access the compiled Java methods as fields.